# custom datagridview cell?

Tags: c#, inheritance, datagridview, interface

I'm doing a project where I need to add a field (let's called it field) to DataGridView cells. The point of this is to be able an extra field in DataGriidView cells which will make the rest of the project far easier.

I've created the following:

```
public class CustomGridRow:DataGridRow{}
public class CustomGridColumn:DataGridViewColumn
{
 public CustomGridColumn 
  {
   This.TemplateCell = new CustomGridTextBoxCell()
  }
}
public class CustomGridTextBoxCell: DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
 public string field;
}
```

Problem: 
If I create a class like (which is what I want to achieve):

```
 public class CustomGridCell: DataGridViewCell{}
```

And move the field to `CustomGridCell`, I would want the `CustomGridTextBoxCell` to inherit from the new `CustomGridCell`, however it does already have a base class of `DataGridViewCell` and C# does not allow a class to inherit two bases classes.

My understanding is the solution comes through `Interfaces`? Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Could you not use an abstract class and then create a concrete class that inherits from it?

Comment: can you illustrate that in an answer? @sr28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class CustomDataGridColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
     this.CellTemplate = new CustomGridTextBoxCell();
}

class CustomGridTextBoxCell : CustomGridCell
{

}

class CustomGridCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    public string fieldA { get; set; }

    public CustomGridCell()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you want to do, I think you could do something like:

```
class CustomGridTextBoxCell : CustomGridCell
{
    public CustomGridTextBoxCell(string field) 
        : base(field)
    {
    }
}

abstract class CustomGridCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    private string _field;

    public CustomGridCell(string field)
    {
        this._field = field;
    }

    public string field
    {
        get { return this._field; }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I've not tested this, it's just a starter for ten.

UPDATE: What about if you changed the abstract class to something like this then:

```
abstract class CustomGridCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    public string field { get; set; };

    public CustomGridCell(string field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

You could also try:

```
class CustomDataGridColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
     this.CellTemplate = new CustomGridTextBoxCell();
}

class CustomGridTextBoxCell : CustomGridCell
{

}

class CustomGridCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    public string fieldA { get; set; }

    public CustomGridCell()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Will test it when I get home and tell ya.

Comment: does seem to be working... what i want to achieve is to create a custom datagridview where its datagridviewcells have a field

Comment: it's not working is what i meant sorry what i want to achieve to be able to have an additional public property of inside the custom gridview cell, i want to be able to set this property called field like this follow customgridview.rows[x].cells[x].field = value

Comment: @Jelly - how about making the previously private string public as per my update? Obviously I've not included your customgridview, custom column etc.

Comment: will test that and  i will tell you

Comment: @Jelly - updated with another example not using an abstract class.

Comment: i'll will try i got caught up with another project sorry